# C# like property get/set instead of private variables and individual getter/setter methods

Tags: java

Is there an equivalent of the C# property call in java?

```
protected int foo2{ get; set; }
```

instead of doing this all the time:

```
private int foo2;
public void setfoo2 (int value) {foo2 = value;}
public int  getfoo2 () {return foo2;}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope.

they are different languages. different ways of doing things. BTW c# too does the same thing in the background. what c# gives is what we call *syntactic sugar*. it gives a shorthand writing.